# Syntax issue with copying zip file from one folder to another with robocopy

Tags: cmd, robocopy

I would like to use robocopy to simply copy a zip file called `Sample.zip` to a local folder called `HERE`.

This is currently my code:

```
ROBOCOPY C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\HERE Z:\Sample.zip
```

I just get an error saying invalid directory.

What is the issue with my syntax here?

Comment: Syntax looks pretty clear in the help file. `ROBOCOPY Source_folder Destination_folder [files_to_copy] [options]`

Comment: Read the doc, Jackson. Read the doc. `ROBOCOPY /?` Note the parameters for source and destination are separate from the name of the file to copy. You would be just as well off using the `COPY` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I respect that you want to use `robocopy` and iminiki's answer, I *won't* recommend it. `robocopy` is mainly used to copy directory structures and/or files remotely although `robocopy` means Robust File Copy. I use `copy` in my batch files for best practice:

```bat
copy "Z:\Sample.zip" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\HERE"
```

which copies `Sample.zip` file from `Z:` to `C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\HERE`. Note that quoting both paths is quite important and a very good practice; do it always.

Comment: Side question, I’d like copy to only copy files that have a newer date modified date. Essentially I want to overwrite a file every time the batch script runs with the newest version of the file, what can I add?

Comment: @JacksonMills, already in many of your questions you have been shown or asked to read the help files for the command you are trying to use.  You don't seem to want to help yourself. Open up a command prompt and type : `copy /?`. But I would also advise you to look at: `xcopy /?`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try separating the file from the origin directory. Try this one:

```
ROBOCOPY Z:\ C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\HERE Sample.zip
```

Comment: Sure. Now swap the directory paths. Source has to come first per the help file.